# textarea auto-detection of RTL characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea in which the user can enter text in English or in Arabic,
so i need an auto-detection of characters typed, if it detects a charCodeAt() > 255 , it automatically switch the direction to RTL using jquery ..

but the code is not wroking !

```js
 function isUnicode(str) {
    var letters = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
        if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) {
            break;
        }
        letters[i] = str.substring(i - 1, i);
        if (letters[i].charCodeAt() > 255) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    window.CP.exitedLoop(1);
    return false;
}
var dir = $('#newstatustxt');
dir.keyup(function (e) {
    if (isUnicode(dir.val())) {
        $(this).css('direction', 'rtl');
  $(this).css('font-family', 'lucida grande,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif');
    } else {
        $(this).css('direction', 'ltr');
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="field">
    <textarea id="newstatustxt" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
```

thank you in advance :)

Comment: The `.charCodeAt()` method returns the UTF-16 encoding (or half of it if it's a high pane character). What does such encoding being greater than 255 have to do with RTL?

Comment: The ISO-Latin-1 codeset ranges from 0 to 255. The first 0 to 127 are a direct match of the ASCII character set.

Comment: Well, Latin-1 can't even store Arabic characters :-?

Comment: so what do you suggest ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with non Latin scripts. If you google for "javascript detect rtl" you get some suggestions.

Comment: i already did! but no solutions founded , thanks :)

Comment: In the end there're only two solutions: filter by character range (for which you need to properly determine the involved character codes in the appropriate encoding) or filter by Unicode properties (for which you need libraries that are normally not included in standard JavaScript engines).